# Как в новом файле Excel записать информацию взятую из существующего файла Excel, с использованием openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

При нажатии на кнопку должны проводиться расчеты и создаваться новый файл Excel.
На данный момент почему-то происходит превышение допустимого диапазона у кортежа в wbsheet[row][1].value = Name2
(обработка начинается со второй строки, т.к. в первой названия столбцов)

```
    def button_action(self):
        wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
        wb.create_sheet('Sheet1')
        wbsheet = wb['Sheet1']
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'AO\Name.xlsx')
        sheet = book['Sheet1']
        col = sheet.max_row ///87
        raschety = int(self.rasch_entry.get())
        for row in range(2, col+1):
            WbId= int(sheet[row][0].value)
            Name2 = int(sheet[row][1].value)
            Name3 = int(sheet[row][3].value)
            Name4 = int(sheet[row][3].value)
            Name5 = int(sheet[row][4].value)
            Name6 = str(sheet[row][5].value)
            Name7 = int(sheet[row][6].value)
            print(WbIda)///1,2,3,4
            if raschety <= Name4:
                Name8 = Name4 / (Name2 * Name3)
                Name9 = Name4 / (Name5 * Name7)
                Name10 = Name8 * Name9 
                wbsheet[row][0].value = WbIda
                wbsheet[row][1].value = Name2 ///IndexError: tuple index out of range
                wbsheet[row][2].value = Name3 
                wbsheet[row][3].value = Name4 
                wbsheet[row][4].value = Name5 
                wbsheet[row][5].value = Name6 
                wbsheet[row][6].value = Name7 
                wbsheet[row][7].value = Name8 
                wbsheet[row][8].value = Name9 
                wbsheet[row][9].value = Name10 
        wb.save('NameDone.xlsx')
```

Comment: for i in (1, col): - это цикл на две итерации (1, 2), и то, что вы внутри него делаете row += 1 ему фиолетово ;)

Comment: 10, но если заменить на 87, все равно обрабатывается 2

Comment: вместо row = 2 нужно rows = sheet.max_row какой-то (посмотрите, как достать к-во строк) и цикл тогда for row in range(1, rows):

Comment: А, совсем забыл про renge. Но проблема записи осталась

Comment: у вас в коде нет записи в новый файл...

Comment: wbsheet[row=1][0].value = WbIda Должна записывать в ячейку A1 переменную WbIda, но это не происходит. Почему-то происходит превышение допустимого диапазона у кортежа wbsheet[row][1].value = Name2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Короче, перед тем как записывать информацию в excel, требуется добавить пустые "ячейки", как я понимаю это нужно именно для библиотеки, т.к. фактически ничего не добавляется.

Как пример:

```
sheet21.append(['', '', '', '', '', '', ''])
```

Тут я добавил 7 "ячеек" т.к. в документе используется 7 столбцов.